# Are django modules global - ImportError: No module named django.core.management?

Tags: python, django

I am quite confused with how django works. I followed some guides and tested a sample app and got it running on my local dev machine. It works great. But when I moved this sample app to my production server, I got this error:

```
# cd /var/www/html/helloapp
# python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

So, during my setup for the sample app, I did this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-django
```

Then:

```
$ django-admin startproject helloapp
```

Then:

```
$ cd /var/www/html/django-project/helloapp/
```

Then:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

Result:

> It worked! Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.

So, I transferred the files helloapp/ into my production server:

```
# cd /var/www/html/helloapp
# python manage.py runserver
```

Then there is the error:

> No module named django.core.management

Do I have to install `python-django` in my production server - **"globally"** as one of my system software in my production server?

What is `django.core.management` for actually? There might be many this kind of modules I need to run my app. So are these modules coming from django's "global" then?

If my system broke or I removed `python-django` one day, all my django apps will break too?

**EDIT:**

I got it running with a virtual env instead, but it seems to have problems with `gunicorn`:

```
$ gunicorn helloapp.wsgi
[2017-05-18 22:33:37 +0000] [882] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2017-05-18 22:33:37 +0000] [882] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (882)
[2017-05-18 22:33:37 +0000] [882] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-05-18 22:33:37 +0000] [886] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 886
[2017-05-18 22:33:37 +0000] [886] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 384, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/var/www/html/django-project/helloapp/helloapp/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
[2017-05-18 22:33:37 +0000] [886] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 886)
[2017-05-18 22:33:37 +0000] [882] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2017-05-18 22:33:37 +0000] [882] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you must have django installed on your production server.
I personally use virtual environments for this matter, try

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
virtualenv env_name
source env_name/bin/activate
```

Once you have done that you should see the name of your environment written in front of your pwd. This will allow you to install python packages ONLY on that environment. But, of course, you're gonna have to use this in your production server as well...

Comment: so if I use `virtual environments` then I don't have to install django - "globally"?

Comment: Correct, you don't have to install django globally. Actually if you run your manage.py file inside your environment HAVING installed django globally but not in your actual environment, it won't run.

Comment: Thanks. How can I transform my sample above into a virtualenv version?

Comment: # cd /var/www/html/helloapp

First: install the virtualenv

sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv

create your env

virtualenv venv_name -p pythonx.x (x.x for default python version Ex.: 3.5, 2.7...)

(now youre already inside your virtualenv), if youre not,
´source venv_name/bin/activate´

Install django

pip install django

run your server

python manage.py runserver

Comment: So `venv_name` is inside `helloapp`?

Comment: Doesn't matter where you create your virtualenv, but yes, it can be inside helloapp.

Comment: ok. still don't get it. then how running `python manage.py runserver` will talk to this `env` instead of the global django?

Comment: you are going to be "inside" the virtualenv with the command `source venv_name/bin/activate` when you run any python command from the terminal using virtualenv, it will automatically check for only the packages that were installed within it.

Comment: OK. got it running now. so I have to run `source venv_name/bin/activate` first and leave it on then running `python manage.py runserver`, right?

Comment: Correct. This way is how you get access to your virtualenv packages (Django, etc.). If you dont run `source venv_name/bin/activate` and run `python manage.py runserver` you are going to run your project using python "global" packages. When using Django, people most of the time create a .txt file with the following command `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. You might want to look into that.

Comment: btw, virtualenv seems does not work with gunicorn. See my edit above.

Comment: I saw the edit, I can't answer that with certainty because it's been a long time since I last used gunicorn, but it shouldn't be a problem to use gunicorn with virtualenv. One thing that you should do when moving your project from computer to computer is what I told you in my last answer, make sure you have installed all the required packages by doing the following: First, in your local dev machine execute `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. Then in your server machine, activate your venv, paste the .txt file somwehere inside your project and execute `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: `requirements.txt` is for installing the packages inside the venv, right?

Comment: Yes. you should activate your venv, and then run the "pip install -r...."

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm you have `Django` installed?

```
sudo pip install django --upgrade
```

---

To use virtualenv, first install it

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Create a new env (should not be inside the Django project)

```
virtualenv my_env
```

Inside this folder, you can activate the env

```
. bin/activate
```

Once the env is active, you install django

```
pip install django
```

Then go back to the django project and running

```
python manage.py runserver
```

should work

[More info here](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

Comment: Ok, you need to have it installed. And yeah using virtualenv is a way to avoid installing it globally, if that's what you want.

Comment: virtualenv is what i want I think. how can I transform my sample above into a virtualenv version?

Comment: Added some instructions.

Comment: I don't quite understand the structure. So the env should not be inside Django project, then where should it be?

Comment: Anywhere you want, just wanted to illustrate that it's independent from Django. You can install anything with pip while it is active, and it's all isolated in that env. Running Django will then work from the location you currently have the django project, as long as the env is active.

Comment: Thanks. I'm lost! Working on NodeJS applications is so much easier and straight-forward!

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to install python-django in my production server

Yes, django must be installed on your production server the same way you installed on your development server

Comment: aww ok. but how come i **don't** need to do so when I run a legacy of a django project? it was developed with django 1.5 - not by me.